# How can I numerically solve equations containing Bessel functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical, bessel-functions, equation-solving

I have confronted an equation containing Bessel functions of the first type on one side and modified Bessel functions of the second type on the other. I want to know its exact solutions (values of u). The equation is as follows:

```
u*besselj(s-1,u)/besselj(s,u)=-w*besselK(s-1,w)/besselk(s,w)
```

where s is an arbitrary integer number, for example 2.

w can be written as a function of u:

```
w=sqrt(1-u^2);
```

and so this equation has only one variable: u

I'm new to MATLAB. I have no idea about how I should approach this. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

A quick thing to try may be the [FZERO](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html) function, a generic nonlinear zero finder. To learn how to use it, you can implement the examples given in the documentation. Then, rewrite your function so it can be input to `fzero` and see what you get..

(Note: I haven't tried this, but I just noticed there were no replies yet so maybe it's better than nothing.)

Comment: Dear Matt;
thanks for your reply
I have tried it before and unfortunately it ignores some primary answers I mean at interval beginning. I don't know why.